# Extracting Values from a comma separated String using Regex

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have string as below:

```
7,TEST-31052019-02,CD12345,CD54321,Success,Deliverable Recipients
```

I want to extract two values from it using Extract Text Processor in `nifi`. One `TEST-31052019-02` and `CD54321`.

I have tried `VF[A-Z]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*` and able to extract `TEST-31052019-02`. How can I extract `CD54321` using same regex?

```
VF[A-Z]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*
```

Expected Output:

```
TEST-31052019-02, CD54321
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that we wish to extract two values, `TEST-31052019-02`

```
([A-Z]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)
```

and `CD54321`

```
([A-Z0-9]+),[A-Z][a-z]
```

which here we use `,[A-Z][a-z]` as a right boundary next to this capturing group:

```
([A-Z0-9]+)
```

We can use alternation, if we like to combine them:

```
([A-Z0-9]+),[A-Z][a-z]|([A-Z]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IidhAX/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could also match 1+ uppercase chars and match either the pattern with a dash or match 1+ digits and use a positive lookahead to assert what follows is an upper and lowercase char:

```
[A-Z]+(?:-[0-9]+-[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?=,[A-Z][a-z]))
```

**Explanation**

- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ uppercase chars
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]+-[0-9]+` Match digits and hyphen pattern
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]+(?=,[A-Z][a-z])` Match 1+ digits and use positive lookahead to assert what is directly to the right is `,` Uppercase lowercase char a-z
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pNW7NF/2)

Note that in your pattern you use 
`[0-9]*-[0-9]*` but the `*` quantifier will repeat 0+ times and it could also match for example `--`

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird.

Comment: Done. Ticked the answer I implemented.